# How to detect specific objects first before selecting region of interests (selectROI) in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tracking

I'm doing a project in multiple object tracking, particularly pedestrians on a streets. I've read about the tracking API in OpenCV and there's a part where you have to specify a ROI (a.k.a. square) around your tracked objects. Yet, I don't know how to make the machine first understand that it needs to detect pedestrians only, and then from the detected people, draw the ROI around that object. Also, the number of people on the street is different in each frame, so how to automate the program to detect the people and then draw that square on them? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, have a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to know what you can ask here.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time here. Is my question out of place @ElouarnLaine?

Comment: Well, as it is, your question is too broad (imo). You need to show some effort: explain what you have tried so far, show the result of your research on the topic, and if you can, post some code. Have you tried this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/09/pedestrian-detection-opencv/)?